# ::Magick not understood in app(Rmagick)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

I made a standalone ruby file and successfully ran on the console to make sure Rmagick was working.However, when i tried using the same code in my rails app, it unfortunately doesn't work

This is my model

```
 class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base
     def crop_photo(url, x, y, w, h)
       image =  Magick::Image.new
       urlimage = open(url)
       image.from_blob(urlimage.read)
       crop = image.crop(x,y,w,h)
       crop.write('pool_cropped.jpg')
     end
 end
```

controller

```
 class ProvidersController < ProviderApplicationController

     def crop
       @provider = current_provider
       coordinates = params["cordinates"]
       image_path = params["path"]
       w = coordinates[0][0]
       h = coordinates[0][1]
       x = coordinates[0][2]
       y = coordinates[0][3]
       @provider.crop_photo(image_path, x, y, w, h)
       redirect_to root_path
     end
  end
```

I tried requiring RMagick, but rails returns a error page saying cannot load such file

this is the error i get when i attempt to crop

```
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4.9ms

    NameError (uninitialized constant Provider::Magick):
    app/models/provider.rb:43:in `crop_photo'
   app/controllers/providers_controller.rb:56:in `crop'
```

any suggestions? I'm using Mac OSX so its not case sensitive

Comment: Does your `Gemfile` say `gem 'rmagick'` or `gem 'rmagick', :require => 'RMagick'`?

Comment: gem 'rmagick', '~> 2.13.3'

Comment: Does adding the `:require` option help?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to put `require` in your Provider(model) Class. 

**First:** check your Gemfile for line: `gem 'rmagick'`
Then, **bundle install**

and finally,

```
require 'RMagick'
class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base
     def crop_photo(url, x, y, w, h)
       image =  Magick::Image.new
       urlimage = open(url)
       image.from_blob(urlimage.read)
       crop = image.crop(x,y,w,h)
       crop.write('pool_cropped.jpg')
     end
end
```